# Magento Multi-Store - Cart Contents Issue

Tags: cookies, shopping-cart, magento-1.8, sessionid

I have a Magento CE 1.8.1 "website" with multiple "stores" on different domains.

We are already using the SessionID in the URL to switch between stores. We have SSLs in place for all the stores that are currently live.

The issue we are having is keeping the contents of the cart for a customer who is not signed in or does not have an account when they switch between stores without using the SID or if they visit one store, leave the website, and navigate to another store manually.

Is there a way this can be solved? I know cookies do not allow cross-domain storage and am hoping to find a fix without paying too much.

Thank you!

Website Info:

Tuga Sunwear - [Main Website/Store](http://tugasunwear.com)
SunBusters Kids - [Second Store](http://sunbusterskids.com)
Molehill Mtn - [Third Store](http://molehillmtn.com)

-----EDITS-----
1) Here are my Session Cookie Management for the WEBSITE - all stores are set to follow config default:
LIFETIME: 5400
PATH: (empty)
DOMAIN: (empty)
HTTP ONLY: YES
RESTRICTION MODE: NO

My store is setup with 1 (one) website and 4 (four) stores. Looking at my "Websites" tab in any product the result is this: [PRODUCT WEBSITE SETTINGS](http://i.imgur.com/fWFgSwb.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, can you check if customer information is shared between multiple stores in Magento configuration? Check admin - System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts.

Another question, Have you tried Turnkey's method here

http://turnkeye.com/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores/

Comment: I have "share customer accounts" set to Global - I have looked at Turnkey's method before and am following steps 1 & 2. Step 3 was attempted but did not produce any desired results, and at one point crashed my checkout process.

I will attempt them again and post my results.

Comment: To clarify, I have 2 questions:

Are your "Session Cookie Management" settings correct for each website scope? 

Check Magento Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web > "Session Cookie Management" > "Cookie Domain" 

Also, the product may need to be available in each website scope in order to appear in each websites shopping cart. For example the "Websites" tab of any given product.

Comment: I have editted the original post to include the information you are asking about. At one point, I had changed the "domain" and "patch" for cookie settings and my site crashed, so i had to edit mySQL to recover it. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: On our multi store - cart sharing did NOT work with empty values for domain. They must be the domain the http request comes in as as far as we know. Have you tried populating these fields with correct domain?

Comment: I have not tried that. To confirm, you are saying I should have the "domain" value be the "unsecure url" for each store? what about the main site setting?

Comment: From what I read on the Magento Wiki this setting helps mainly with subdomains - as my stores on different domain names, is this still something I should try?

Comment: Please allow me to test your specific scenario first before changes are made. Will post update ASAP.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking forward to hearing your results!